# DOC type issue in IE 8 and 9

Tags: html, doctype

When I use the bellow DOC type in jsp page, the styles of some hyperlinks are changed in IE8 and IE9.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

With the below doctype it shows correctly. All the hyperlinks are aligned to left

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

But when I add the below doctype the style was changed. All the hyperlinks moved to centered position.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Can anybody please suggest how to resolve this issue in IE 8 and 9? Others browsers it works as expected.

Comment: (1) Use a **valid** Doctype taken from an HTML specification. Using the public identifier for HTML 4.0 Transitional and the system identifier for XHTML 1.0 Strict is nonsense. (2) Make sure you pick a Doctype that triggers standards mode (i.e. not Transitional with no system identifier). (3) Just use the HTML 5 Doctype. `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`. (4) If you don't get the layout you expect, then **your CSS is probably wrong** and you need to debug it instead of looking at the Doctype.

Comment: Your code uses CSS incorrectly in a manner that corresponds to bugs in old versions of IE. This is why you think the page “works” when using an incorrect DOCTYPE declaration, which triggers “quirks mode” (bug simulation mode). But you have shown absolutely nothing about your HTML elements and CSS code, so there is no way to help you fix the problems in them.